# Installing Julia on Atom

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I am trying to install Julia on Atom. What I made already is that I installed Julia in this folder :
E:\Program files\Users\Zeedo\AppData\Local\Julia-0.6.3

and I installed Atom. Then, I also installed language-Julia package.

Now, when I want to run a code, I get this error:

> Julia could not be started.
>   We tried to launch Julia from:
>   julia
>   This path can be changed in the settings.
>   Details:
>     '"julia"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

So, I don't know where should I give the Julia address to the Atom.Or, if you know something that I am doing wrong, please let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Atom cannot run code by default, so that error message must be being thrown by a community package you've installed. Searching shows me the package is most likely `atom-julia-client`. And the error seems to be because it can't find the Julia binary it needs to run the program.

First, you should make sure you can run the `julia` command from the command line directly, which you can check by running `julia --version`. If this doesn't work, then you need to add the Julia binary to your path.

If the above didn't work, try go to Settings -> Packages -> `julia-client`. In here, the first setting is `Julia Path`, which is defaulted to `julia` (like in the error). Change this to an absolute path, directly to the binary (or to the folder containing the binary; try both if the first doesn't work).

FYI, the `language-julia` package just gives you syntax highlighting and snippets, and doesn't actually need any Julia stuff to work.